# Launching a script when connecting a Raspberry USB key

Tags: bash, usb, raspberry-pi3

I'm here to ask you a question I'm currently in internship, I have a project on Raspberry that consists in automatically launching a slide show when connecting a USB key, I would like to know how to launch a script when connecting a USB key, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in

Comment: What I would like if it is possible is when I plug a USB key into my Raspberry a script to customize this lance.